# How to Curve an SVG image

Tags: svg, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to manipulate SVG images so as to perform a "curve" transformation. I would ideally want to use something like the DOMMatrix transformations for translation, rotation, skewing, etc. Essentially, I would like to create a transformation matrix where the skew angle updates with the x coordinate, so that the coordinate system becomes curved.

This sticker head is drawn in SVG and I would like it to be drawn following the red bezier curves:

[image: SVG curve process]

I have looked at converting every element in the picture into paths and then into curves, so as to manipulate each curve individually. I am sure there is some way to mathematically figure out how each individual path has to be updated, but this seems very complex. Ideally I would like to apply a curve transformation directly to a group, but this option does not seem to exist.
I have also looked at filters such as the fedisplacementmap, but it has not lead me anywhere. Needless to say, I'm stuck.

If anyone has any ideas on how I might solve this, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transformations.

Comment: If you want to give feDisplacementMap a solid try - this is a good blog on how to create a robust one. What you're trying to do is not possible to do with the built-in SVG transforms. http://www.tapper-ware.net/blog/perspective-texture-with-6-lines-of-svg/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has issues with this and stumbles upon this thread. I eventually solved the problem through tessellation.
You can divide your SVG into several columns. Then, you apply a skew on the ones from the left to the center column trending in a "downward" curve.
The center column is left untouched.
The columns from the center column to the right get a skew going "upwards".
Obivously, the skew has to change according to some function/variable, so that it is not linear, or we would end up with a V-shaped curve.
What's also important, is that you need to calculate the height difference. For example, if I skew my rectangle by 5 degrees, use a sine function to calculate the height difference that this manipulation results in. This height difference is how you know where to place the next rectangle on the y-axis.
Here is a real example of what the result looks like: [Example Application](https://originalpeople.com/personalised-custom-mugs-and-cups.html#product-builder-section)